# eslint won't update past v4.5.0, "Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-google'"

Tags: eslint

I had an old version of `eslint`:

```
eslint -v
v4.5.0
```

To update `eslint` I ran:

```
npm install -g eslint
```

The response said that `eslint@5.9.0` had been installed successfully. Following the instructions in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) in my project root I ran

```
eslint --init
```

I selected the Google style guide. The install said

```
The style guide "google" requires eslint@>=5.4.0. You are currently using eslint@4.5.0.
  Do you want to upgrade? (Y/n)
```

That seemed odd, as I'd just installed 5.9.0, but I said Yes. The response said that the installation was successful:

```
Successfully created .eslintrc.json file in /Users/TDK/LanguageTwo
ESLint was installed locally. We recommend using this local copy instead of your globally-installed copy.
```

Then I ran

```
eslint -v
v4.5.0
```

I checked `echo $PATH` and didn't see anything like `eslintvm` locking in an old version.

I tried to lint a file and got this error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-google'
```

eslint v5.9.0 is now installed locally in my project root and I can see `eslint-config-google` in the node modules. eslint 5.9.0 is installed globally. My guess is that the "missing" `eslint-config-google` is because my computer is still running eslint v4.5.0. I restarted my computer. What is keeping eslint at v4.5.0?

Comment: This morning I ran eslint -v and it said v5.9.0, apparently multiple computer restarts were required. I still have the error message "Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-google'".

Answer (score 0):

I used find . -name 'eslint' to remove every copy of eslint from every directoty. `npm uninstall -g eslint` didn't remove every module. Then I reinstalled eslint and ran `eslint init`. Now it's at v5.9.0. It still has the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-google'
```

I don't know what's causing this problem.